# Initialise the vertical alignment of contenteditable div cursor with css

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following:

```css
  #container {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width:150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: grid;
    vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #container:focus {
      align-items: center;
      vertical-align: middle; 
      text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div id='container' contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

I'd like to have the cursor initialise in the center of the div container. At present, it starts at the top (Chrome) or bottom (Firefox). It centralises as soon as I start typing.

**How do I initialise the vertical alignment of contenteditable div cursor with css?**

Comment: added another idea for firefox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `display:table-cell;`, it should work better than `grid` (seems to work only with Chrome)

```css
#container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align:center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div id='container' contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

A *hacky* idea to make it work with Firefox where you need the div to be empty:

```css
#container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align:center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#container:empty {
  line-height:150px;
  padding-left:75px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div id='container' contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is very short.

```css
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: orange;
}
.div:empty{
    line-height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" placeholder="Type something" contenteditable></div>
```